# How to check if an array contains any elements of another array

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

Here I've an array ["chair","desk","charger"], I'd like to check if a different array contains any the elements in the first array.

Example:

```
["chair","desk"] //returns true;

["screen","charger","computer"] //returns true;

["calendar", "screen"] //returns false;
```

How could this be done in Presto SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check cardinality of array returned by array_intersect(x, y) function.

Demo:

```
with mydata as (
select 1 id, array['chair','desk'] as myarray union all
select 2 id, array['screen','charger','computer']  union all
select 3 id, array['calendar', 'screen']
)

select id, 
       cardinality(array_intersect(myarray, array['chair','desk','charger']))>0 as contains_flag
  from mydata
 order by id
```

Result:

```
id  contains_flag
1   TRUE
2   TRUE
3   FALSE
```

Comment: Thats great. Thanks a mill!